# Использование EPOLLONESHOT в многопоточной среде

Tags: c++, linux, многопоточность, epoll

Появилась необходимость написать многопоточный сервер на c++, используя механизм `EPOLL`.

Реализация с пулом потоков не подходит, так как передача задания в пул потоков занимает много драгоценного времени, вследствие чего иногда ощущаются подлагивания. Решил реализовать след образом: несколько потоков будут ожидать события от одного дескриптора Epoll'а.

Вопрос: как нужно правильно использовать опцию `EPOLLONESHOT`? Нужно ли что-то синхронизировать мьютексами, или же реализация epoll'a уже позаботилась об этом? Принципиально ли использовать `egde-triggered` режим? По возможности прошу предоставить код/псевдокод подобной реализации. Поиск в гугле/яндексе ничего толкового не дал.

Comment: Начните с чтения man 7 epoll. Кое-какие примеры есть [тут](http://pastebin.com/vbMLKhrB) / А также почитайте (возможно особое внимание следует уделить комментариям) в общем-то немногочисленные  обсуждения использования *epoll* на этом сайте (imho проще всего запросить гугл `site:ru.stackoverflow.com epoll`)

Comment: в man 7 epoll слишком мало информации про EPOLLONESHOT, лишь поверхностная информация, которая не дает мне точного представления. В примере, который вы мне предоставили вообще не используется опция EPOLLONESHOT. Поиск инфы по форуму толкового не дал. Просьба предоставить информацию по сабжу.

Comment: Я ни разу не экспериментировал с EPOLLONESHOT (видимо остальные 17 человек, которые просмотрели этот пост, тоже). Интуитивно, эту опцию стоит использовать в ситуации, когда получение ожидаемых даннных  меняет алгоритм работы с дескриптором, поскольку он изымается из пула получаемых событий. Регулярное же (для каждой порции данных) использование EPOLLONESHOT (опять интуитивно) представляется неэффективным (лишние syscall).

Answer (score 3):

`EPOLLONESHOT` нужно для того, что бы `epoll_wait()` сработал только один раз. Если у вас несколько потоков ждут на одном epoll дескрипторе, то произойдёт это только в одном из них. После чего, нужно взводить его заново (+1 сискол).

В случае Edge Triggered (`EPOLLET`) у вас просто будет срабатывать epoll только по изменению состоянию в сокете. И снова - сработает это только в одном ожидающем треде. Взводить заново больше не нужно. Ну и логику нужно строить так, что бы в обработчике или писать до тех пор пока не случится `EAGAIN` или читать до тех же пор. Тут,  кстати, тоже собака порылась, что нужна правильноя синхронизация: ты можешь закончить работать с сокетом, но не закончить работать с данными, которые ты от туда прочитал, при этом может случиться изменения состояния сокета снова (например данные идут потоково), соответственно проснётся другой поток и начнёт работать обработчик, будет ли потом гонка по данным - вопрос логики твоего сервера.

Собственно про потокобезопасность на старшем SO есть обсуждения:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058737/is-epoll-thread-safe
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283900/epoll-with-edge-triggering-one-shot-and-multithreading

Есть ещё неплохая презенташка:
http://www.csh.rit.edu/~rossdylan/presentations/EpollMT/ (можно начинать с 14 слайда: http://www.csh.rit.edu/~rossdylan/presentations/EpollMT/#14)

Кстати, списывался с Марком (Marc Lehmann, разработчиком libev), с epoll edge-triggered модой постоянно какие-то артефакты вылазят. Хотя разработчик nxweb его активно в этой форме и использует.

Сам, пока, напрямую не использую epoll, т.к. задачи, обычно, стоят в русле кросс-платформенности и возможности (пусть и не опитимальной) работы на Windows. Использую libev. В любом случае, придерживаюсь подхода, что создаётся пул потоков, в каждом потоке делается свой epoll_create1 и каждый поток работает, по сути, со своим циклом. Каждый сокет, единожды попав в цикл, там и обслуживается и обработка данных по нему не скачет по разным потокам, что немного упрощает синхронизацию.